# Cucumber Scenario Outline with Special Characters

Tags: ruby, unicode, cucumber

I'm currently trying to test a service that should be properly replacing certain special characters within a certain Unicode range, including emojis, transportation icons, emoticons and dingbats. I have been using Cucumber and Ruby to do the testing, and my latest scenario outline won't work. I've tried looking up other ways of getting the character from the examples table, however I can't seem to get it working, and the cucumber printout just complains that the Given step isn't defined.

Here is my feature scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: I update a coupon with a name including emojis/emoticons/dingbats/symbols
Given I have a name variable with a <character> included
When I patch my coupon with this variable
Then the patch should succeed
And the name should include replacement characters

Examples:
| character |
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
| ☀         |
| ☂         |
| ✋        |
| ✂         |
| ⨕         |
|          |
|         |
```

And Here is my step definition for the Given (which is the step that is complaining that it isn't defined)

```
Given(/^I have a name variable with a (\w+) included$/) do |char|
  @name = 'min length ' + char
  @json = { 'name' => @name }.to_json
end
```

I've tried using some regex's to capture the character, and a (\w+) and (\d+), although I can't find information on how to capture the special character. It's possible for me to write 11 different step definitions, but that would be such poor practice it would drive me nuts.

Comment: Unless you have spaces in your specials, it’s safe to use _dot_ `(/^I have a name variable with a (.+?) included$/` or _non-space_ `\S`:  `(/^I have a name variable with a (\S+) included$/`.  `\w` would not give you the desired result, since `\w` is resolved to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: (\S+) worked perfectly, however the (.+?) didn't for some reason. Write it up as an answer though please so I can give you credit! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have spaces in your specials, it’s safe to use *non-space* `\S`:

```
Given(/^I have a name variable with a (\S+) included$/) do |char|
   ...
```

`\w` would not give you the desired result, since `\w` is resolved to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.